# DirectX 11 How Do Vertex And Pixel Shaders Work

Tags: directx, shader, directx-11, vertex-shader

I am reading the book, "Practical Rendering and Computation with Direct3D 11" and looking at the DirectX 11 Sample:

CPP:
https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/blob/master/Direct3D11Tutorials/Tutorial02/Tutorial02.cpp

HLSL:
https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/blob/master/Direct3D11Tutorials/Tutorial02/Tutorial02.fx

**What is this?**

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
 {
  { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
 };
```

**More importantly the Shader -- Where in the program does it set this "Pos"?**

```
float4 VS( float4 Pos : POSITION ) : SV_POSITION
{
    return Pos;
}
```

I can only see that you are binding the vertex data via:

```
// Create vertex buffer
SimpleVertex vertices[] =
{
    XMFLOAT3( 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f ),
    XMFLOAT3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
    XMFLOAT3( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
};
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( SimpleVertex ) * 3;
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
InitData.pSysMem = vertices;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pVertexBuffer );
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;

// Set vertex buffer
UINT stride = sizeof( SimpleVertex );
UINT offset = 0;
g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset );

// Set primitive topology
g_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST );
```

And then you are setting the shaders and then drawing the 3 verticies:

```
// Render a triangle
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader( g_pVertexShader, nullptr, 0 );
g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader( g_pPixelShader, nullptr, 0 );
g_pImmediateContext->Draw( 3, 0 );
```

This all makes sense.  But I am confused on what this Pos input is, how it is generated, and why is it used?  Also, there are other examples that do the same thing ... (sample 7) where they used postion and textures, but I can not see where this information is coming from.  For example...

```
struct VS_INPUT
{
  float4 Pos : POSITION;
  float2 Tex : TEXCOORD0;
};
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: In this context, POSITION is vertex position in object space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array of `D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC` determines the layout of data that will be read from a vertex buffer. This array is passed to a `ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout` call so that it can be used. It is then set on the rendering context via a call `ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetInputLayout` (not shown, but in the code you linked).

If you look at the members of [`D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476180(v=vs.85).aspx), the first member is `SemanticName` (set to `"POSITION"`), which is how elements of the vertex buffer are matched to inputs in the shader. It also contains data about the offset of the data and the format (in this case, the offset is zero, and the format `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT` corresponds to 3x 32bit floats). You'll notice that in the shader, after `Pos`, there's a colon, followed by `"POSITION"` - this is the semantic, and is matched to the input layout. The shader then knows that it should read the position data from offset zero, and the format of that data.

The data itself is read from the vertex buffer, set with the `ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers` call. The `stride` parameters tells the input assembler the distance in the vertex buffer from one vertex to the next, so it knows where to start reading the next one. The `g_pVertexBuffer` passed in was initialized from the `vertices` data, which as you can see is a set of 3x 32-bit floats.

For shaders with additional inputs (eg. `TEXCOORD0`), there will be more entries in the `D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC` array, corresponding to the semantics used in the shaders.

Comment: Okay!  And what if you wanted to use a custom Variable?  You would have to encode it into a texture, or vertex buffer?  Thanks!

Comment: You can use any semantics you like, as long as they match between the input layout and shader.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx#VS - So you have to use Semantics is what im trying to say?  You cant just make up your own?  I guess the semantic tells HLSL how it will behave?  For example, you could have TEXCOORD0 (2 32bit values) inside of a POSITION (3 32bit values) and just ignore z.  Correct?

Comment: In D3D9, the vertex semantics generally had to correspond to the "Vertex Shader Semantics" list in that link, because its version of the `D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC` array (the `D3DVERTEXELEMENT9` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172630(v=vs.85).aspx only allowed for those predefined types). In D3D11, those semantics are still usable, but don't mean anything "special", you can use whatever semantics you'd like, aside from the System Value (SV_) ones, as they are reserved.

Comment: I could use the Semantics called: "THIS_IS_NOT_A_DX11_SEMANTIC", inplace of "POSITION", and it would not effect anything?  And if so, why even have semantics?  Also, if you were to take away the "POSITION" semantics, or not use them at all, how does the Output Merger know how to process the information?  I assume somewhere it has to tell the GPU how to actually process the data to output it to the screen!